# Dynamics 365 Portal - Conflict between contacts exists in multiple business units

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-portals

There is contact based portal registration.
In CRM a person can exists in multiple business units.
Now when a user try to login, it says password incorrect because it is referring to the other contact which is not having the password but same emailId.
I want to enable portal for all the contacts in the system, based up on the business unit I will show the menu items.

suggest changes in portal setup so that it can handle multiple contacts for the user

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to think again about your implementation idea based on [Administrator's Guide to Portal Capabilities for Microsoft Dynamics 365](http://download.microsoft.com/download/6/9/C/69C7ABEA-5457-4B63-876F-F4F3B63495EC/Administrator's%20Guide%20to%20Portal%20Capabilities%20for%20Microsoft%20Dynamics%20365.pdf).

Few points:

1. Multiple contacts is not a good idea, that too with the same email address. Not sure which Business Units (BU) you are talking about, but how you are planning to hook the authentication piece by different BU?  Use the same Contact and after authentication, decide the authorization part based on your concept
2. Even different Contact with different Email for different purpose is ok, but I would recommend you to look at web roles instead
3. If Menu items has to be dynamic & depends on configurations, use `Liquid syntax` rather than complex implementations. [Read more](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/portals/liquid/hybrid-navigation-render-page-hierachy)

Comment: Thanks Arun, We have different business units like HR , Finance and they can create contacts in their respective business units. Now when a user from Finance register from portal he can login successfully. If HR team creates a contact in their business unit with same email I'd, then if portal user try to login it says invalid login.

Comment: @RameshKumar that’s not a good approach to follow, that too for Authentication purpose.. it should be a single record with multiple teams or something.. or else different portals for different BU.. maybe..

Comment: Thanks Arun for your quick review and reply. Using one email id in different business units for contacts is existing business scenario.  That they have different contacts set per business units

Comment: @RameshKumar having redundant master records distinguished by owning BU will result in chaos. Not sure why it’s built that way..

Comment: What's the best way to maintain this master records and access to different business units

Comment: @RameshKumar master records should be unique & should be at Org level, security roles should have Read, Append, AppendTo privileges at Org level. This is how I do.

Comment: @RameshKumar if this answer was helpful, upvote/mark it for others finding it useful